# Concatenation of 2 strings and superscript

Tags: excel, vba, string-formatting, string-concatenation, superscript

My issue is that i have 3 cells A1 , B1 and C1  ; A1 contains a number, B1 a string and C1 contains the concatenation of B1 and A1 . Let's say A1 contains the value 1 and B1 the value "Test" ; I want C1 to Contain Test1 but with 1 as a superscript . Here's the code i've written but that isn't working :

```
Sub exposantmiseenforme()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim C As Range
    Dim l As Integer

    l = Len(Range("B1"))
    C = Range("C1")

    With C.Characters(Start:=l, Length:=l + 1).Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Normal"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = True
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With

End Sub
```

Thank's in advance for your help !

Comment: It may be helpful to show an example of what your output is currently, even if it's not what you want. That may help in error diagnosis.

Comment: I have never seen the use of >>>> in VBA code like that. What's the purpose?

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following (assuming you have more rows than just cells A1 & B1):

***Sample data:***

[image]

***Code:***

```
Sub SuperScriptTxt()

Dim rng As Range, cl As Range, lr As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change accordingly
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("C2:C" & lr)
    For Each cl In rng
        cl.Value = cl.Offset(, -2) & cl.Offset(, -1) 'Leave out this line, if concatenated values are actually already in place.
        cl.Characters(Len(cl.Offset(, -2)) + 1, Len(cl.Offset(, -1))).Font.SuperScript = True
    Next cl
End With

End Sub
```

***Result:***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a Set line 6:

```
Set C = Range("C1")
```

This is actually what you want to suberscript the last character of a string in C1 on the active sheet:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Characters(Start:=Len(Range("C1").Value), _
Length:=1).Font.Superscript = True
```

The way you wrote it it should superscript the entire text, not just the 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
Sub exposantmiseenforme()

Dim l As Integer

l = Len(Range("B1"))
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Characters(l + 1, 1).Font.Superscript = True

End Sub
```

Hope it helps. (I am supposing that that cell is already formulated)