# How to combine multiple excel cells with formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I have 6 cells A1 to F1 (Shown below) in excel

[image]

How to concatenate all six cells but my cells with numbers should be subscript. Finally, I should get something like below for each row.
[image]

It is a lot of work to do subscript on each and every cell.
Previously I found a VBA code to combine two cells ([Concatenation of 2 strings and superscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57989545/concatenation-of-2-strings-and-superscript)).

Comment: So how have you started to edit the code you found?

Comment: Yes. It works for me and is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Call SubscriptIt(Range("A1:H9"))
End Sub

Sub SubscriptIt(rng As Range)

    Dim row As Range, cell As Range
    Dim col As New Collection, v, ar
    Dim i As Integer, s As String

    For Each row In rng.Rows
        Set col = Nothing
        s = ""
         
        ' determine position,length of numbers
        For Each cell In row.Cells
            If IsNumeric(cell) Then
               col.Add Len(s) & ":" & Len(cell)
            End If
            s = s & cell
        Next
    
        ' output in next column
        Set cell = row.Cells(1, rng.Columns.Count + 1)
        cell = s
        cell.Font.Subscript = False
      
        ' apply formatting
        For Each v In col
           ar = Split(v, ":")
           cell.Characters(ar(0) + 1, ar(1)).Font.Subscript = True
        Next
 
     Next
     MsgBox rng.Rows.Count & " rows updated"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code. It presumes that your 6 cells start in column A and inserts the result in column G.

```
Sub CombineAndFormat()
    ' 212
    
    Dim Fun     As String           ' output string
    Dim Arr     As Variant          ' one row's data
    Dim Chars() As Integer          ' element length
    Dim n       As Integer          ' character count
    Dim i       As Long             ' loop counter: index
    Dim R       As Long             ' loop counter: rows
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False          ' speeds up execution
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")       ' change to suit
        ' loop through rows 2 to end of column A
        For R = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Arr = .Range(.Cells(R, 1), .Cells(R, 6)).Value
            ReDim Chars(1 To UBound(Arr, 2))
            Fun = ""
            n = 0
            
            For i = 1 To UBound(Arr, 2)
                Chars(i) = Len(Arr(1, i))
                Fun = Fun & CStr(Arr(1, i))
            Next i
            
            With .Cells(R, 7)
                .Value = Fun
                With .Font                          ' this is the base font
    '                .Name = "Calibri"              ' specify to suit
    '                .FontStyle = "Regular"
                    .Size = 11
                    .Subscript = False
                End With
                For i = 1 To 6 Step 2
                    With .Characters(Start:=n + Chars(i) + 1, Length:=Chars(i + 1)).Font
                        ' this is the subscripted font:-
    '                    .Name = "Calibri"              ' specify to suit
    '                    .FontStyle = "Regular"
                        .Subscript = True
                    End With
                    n = n + Chars(i) + Chars(i + 1)
                Next i
            End With
        Next R
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Variatus, Thank you very much. It is perfect.

Comment: @Prasad I'm glad my code worked for you. Please mark it as "Selected" so that it might also work for others. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function Subscript()

'Define Variables
Dim A, B, C, D, E, F As String
Dim l_A, l_B, l_C, l_D, l_E, l_F As Integer

'Read the content of the cells in row 2
A = Worksheets("Sheet14").Cells(2, 1).Value
B = Worksheets("Sheet14").Cells(2, 2).Value
C = Worksheets("Sheet14").Cells(2, 3).Value
D = Worksheets("Sheet14").Cells(2, 4).Value
E = Worksheets("Sheet14").Cells(2, 5).Value
F = Worksheets("Sheet14").Cells(2, 6).Value

'Get the length of each string in the second row
l_A = Len(A)
l_B = Len(B)
l_C = Len(C)
l_D = Len(D)
l_E = Len(E)
l_F = Len(F)

'Write the content of all cells together in the second row in the column G
Worksheets("Sheet14").Cells(2, 7).Value = A & B & C & D & E & F
'Write the content of Cell B as Subscript in Column G
Worksheets("Sheet14").Cells(2, 7).Characters(l_A + 1, l_B).Font.Subscript = True
'Write the content of Cell D as Subscript in Column G
Worksheets("Sheet14").Cells(2, 7).Characters(l_A + l_B + l_C + 1, l_D).Font.Subscript = True
'Write the content of Cell F as Subscript in Column G
Worksheets("Sheet14").Cells(2, 7).Characters(l_A + l_B + l_C + l_D + l_E + 1, l_F).Font.Subscript = True

End Function
```